# Can I hide the Commands and Code Section in NetLogo Model?

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way to remove the Command Center and NetLogo Code sections from a NetLogo model when exported by HTML? I want to give this model for other people to interact with without having them look at the code. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Don't feel ashamed, this happens to quite a lot of new contributors. Can you please give what you have tried?

Comment: I right clicked on the HTML page that I exported from my NetLogo model and clicked on "Inspect Element". Then I Command+F "Command Center". I right-clicked on the line starting with "<div class="netlogo-tab-area" and clicked on Delete -> Node. This worked but when I refresh the page it comes back. Is there a way to permanently hide this section?

Comment: Use CSS. DevTools only edits the source for this session and gets cleared when the page is left. (Try it: Open your developer tools and delete the whole <body> tag of this page, then reload and it will be restored.)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I right-clicked on my .html file I had exported from my NetLogo and Open With Atom (my code editor of choice). I then deleted the following lines and it worked!:

```
<div class="netlogo-tab-area" style="min-width: {{Math.min(width, 500)}}px; max-width: {{Math.max(width, 500)}}px">
    {{# !isReadOnly }}
    <label class="netlogo-tab{{#showConsole}} netlogo-active{{/}}">
      <input id="console-toggle" type="checkbox" checked="{{showConsole}}" />
      <span class="netlogo-tab-text">Command Center</span>
    </label>
    {{#showConsole}}
      <console output="{{consoleOutput}}" isEditing="{{isEditing}}" checkIsReporter="{{checkIsReporter}}" />
    {{/}}
    {{/}}
    <label class="netlogo-tab{{#showCode}} netlogo-active{{/}}">
      <input id="code-tab-toggle" type="checkbox" checked="{{ showCode }}" />
      <span class="netlogo-tab-text{{#lastCompileFailed}} netlogo-widget-error{{/}}">NetLogo Code</span>
    </label>
    {{#showCode}}
      <codePane code='{{code}}' lastCompiledCode='{{lastCompiledCode}}' lastCompileFailed='{{lastCompileFailed}}' isReadOnly='{{isReadOnly}}' />
    {{/}}
    <label class="netlogo-tab{{#showInfo}} netlogo-active{{/}}">
      <input id="info-toggle" type="checkbox" checked="{{ showInfo }}" />
      <span class="netlogo-tab-text">Model Info</span>
    </label>
    {{#showInfo}}
      <infotab rawText='{{info}}' isEditing='{{isEditing}}' />
    {{/}}
  </div>
```